# Why does my update statement want a schema

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio

I have a DataWeave script to remove all non-numeric characters from a phone number field. The code works correctly in the DataWeave Playground, but throws an error in Anypoint Studio. The payload is

```
{
  "Recipient": {
    "Name": "Bob Newhart",
    "MailingAddress": {
      "Line1": "123 Main Street",
      "Line2": "Apt 5",
      "City": "Cumming",
      "State": "GA",
      "ZipCode": "30009",
      "ZipCodePlus4": "3382"
    },
    "PhoneNumber": "(999) 555-1234",
    "Company": "Disney"
  }
}
```

And the script is

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(
  payload: payload update {case .Recipient.PhoneNumber -> replace (payload.Recipient.PhoneNumber, /\D/) with ""}
).payload
```

I am running this version of Anypoint Studio

```
Version: 7.4.2
Build Id: 202001311805
```

and the error message returned by Anypoint Studio is:
**Invalid input "update {case ", expected schema or & (line 6, column 20):**

Comment: Is the error happening at design time or execution time? Please copy the complete error message with all lines.
You are running an older version of Studio. Does the issue reproduce with the latest and greatest release, currently 7.8.0? There are many fixes and improvements in the last versions.

Comment: And as importantly, which Mule version is used for this project?

Comment: The error is being returned at design time. The installation details show that I am using "Mule Server Runtime 4.2.2 EE". I wasn't aware that there was a newer release of Anypoint Studio. I will need to check with the senior dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [update operator was added in Mule 4.3.0](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/anypoint-platform/update-fields-with-dataweave/). If you are using an older Mule version it won't be available. Probably Studio 7.4.2 doesn't know about it either.

Comment: Thank you. I will submit a new question requesting assistance on updating a payload field using a regular expression. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also found out the senior dev was already using 7.8 of the studio and 4.3 of the runtime. So, thank you for that as well!

Comment: You can't upgrade from 7.4 to 7.8. You will need to install a fresh download of 7.8. About the version of Mule Runtime, you should use the one that you are going to deploy to. Mule 4.3 is recommended, but you should not develop in 4.3 and try to deploy to 4.1. You can install all Mule 4.x runtimes into Studio 7.8 if you want to use a previous version.